# remotedisplay.jar and provider.jar does not exist or contains no resources

Tags: android, firebase, compilation

My project which was running perfectly yesterday is throwing some error without any change in the code.

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
> **com.google.firebase.auth not found.** W/DynamiteModule: Local module
> descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>
> :
>
> Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
> android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
> android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
> would have **incorrectly overridden** the package-private method in
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>
> :
>
> W/ResourcesManager: Asset path
> '/system/framework/com.android.media.**remotedisplay.jar' does not exist**
> or contains no resources.
>
> W/ResourcesManager: Asset path
> '/system/framework/com.android.location.**provider.jar' does not exist**
> or contains no resources.

Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.github.ocaparrostortosa.MyApplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I found similar problems on SO with no answer so I questioned the same.

Comment: ¡RESOLVED! I just needed to establish a stable internet connection.

Comment: I would suggest to put is as an answer with the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡RESOLVED! I just needed to establish a stable internet connection